# 2 Google Sheets Workbooks linked via importrage - how to add new row in one workbook and not affect other

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 google workbooks.  One is a rate sheet and the other is a vendor list with pricing.

I have the vendor list with pricing workbook linked to the rate sheet workbook via importrage command.  This works great and everything updates as it should until you add a new line or remove a line to the rate sheet workbook.  At this point the vendor workbook does not update the reference and just still points at the same lines it was originally, now displaying the incorrect data.

How can I dynamically have the vendor list workbook notice the addition or removal of lines in the rate sheet workbook and update the importrange formula?

Can this be done?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have prepared 2 sample workbooks.  They are Test sheet 1 - Rates and Test Sheet 2 Lanes

I have all of our rates in the first sheet.  In the second we would have vendor lanes.  This sheet consists of multie tabs all with an individual lane that is linked to 1 row in the rates sheet.

In the lanes sheet I have linked the two together via importrange in cell A8.  Now this works and links properly, that is until you insert a new line in the rates sheet above the one the lane is linked to and then it doesn't update but shows what the new line information is.

Is there a way to have the lanes sheet dynamically update to the next line when a new line is inserted in the rates sheet?

two sheets links are as follows:

[Rates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JD45y-0-37Kh2KsHnRAMuB0quPtMVuLKuT1qjnNcm1Q/edit?usp=sharing)

[Lanes](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJ4-XKsP5gyyr4mcL5O6l410d7lC91KCm8INZZ9QOig/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data in the same structure you use daily? It would be much easier to answer your question then. Thx

Comment: Have edited with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1 - if you need to check only one condition

To achieve desired result you have to have something like an ID for every rate. For sake of this answer (based on your example sheets) I assume that this could be an Origin City. In Test Sheet 2 I have added new sheet - SheetTest where:

**First step**

I am looking for the row number where desire City reside in Rates sheet (in example - its Mcclellan city). The code for that is simple:

```
MATCH(A2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JD45y-0-37Kh2KsHnRAMuB0quPtMVuLKuT1qjnNcm1Q/edit","Rates!B:B"),0).
```

This gives me -> 10

**Second step**

I use this result to dynamically generate final range - "Rates!A10:X10". The final result in A8 cell is (to make it clearer, I change an address of a sheet to -othersheeturl- :

```
=IMPORTRANGE(
  "-othersheeturl-",
  "Rates!A"&
      MATCH(A2,IMPORTRANGE(-othersheeturl-","Rates!B:B"),0)
      &":X"&
      MATCH(A2,IMPORTRANGE("-othersheeturl-","Rates!B:B"),0)
)
```

[Working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJ4-XKsP5gyyr4mcL5O6l410d7lC91KCm8INZZ9QOig/edit#gid=261740383)

**Warning**

I see that in your original sheet you use "take" Origin City from Rates sheet, so I remove this dependency in A2 to make it an ID. I hope this solves your problem.

## Solution 2 - if you need to check many conditions

An approach is the same, but tools are different. Main goal is to find a row number that meets criteria - "From City" and "To City". Then this row number will be used to concatenate desire range.

### First step - some cleaning

To better manage complex formulas its a good idea to divide them into smaller pieces - like in "ordinary" programing. So, we have:

**From City** in **A5**

```
New Albany
```

**To City** in **B5**

```
Calgary
```

**Rate sheet** (external sheet) url in **B1**:

```
1JD45y-0-37Kh2KsHnRAMuB0quPtMVuLKuT1qjnNcm1Q
```

You don't have to put whole URL, only this part is needed

**Formula that counts row number that we are looking for** in **B2**

```
=QUERY(
{IMPORTRANGE(B1,"A1:B"),
ArrayFormula(row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROWS(IMPORTRANGE(B1,"A1:B")))))},
"select Col3 where Col1='"&B5&"' and Col2='"&A5&"'
limit 1")
```

Above code:

1. Build an array from Rate sheet (external) - columns A1:B and virtual index that represents rows numbers
2. Then, show only column nr 3 (index) where Col1 matches our "To City" and Col2 matches "From City"
3. At the end is a limit to only one result (in case that there are more then one maches)

**Desire range** in **B3**

```
="Rates!A"&B2&":X"&B2
```

**Final formula that renders desire data** from external sheet in **A11**

```
=IMPORTRANGE(B1,B3)
```

[Working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJ4-XKsP5gyyr4mcL5O6l410d7lC91KCm8INZZ9QOig/edit#gid=1831561460)

### Final thoughts

1. You can either hide rows 1-3 or you can pack all above formulas into one. Its up to you. I prefer the first approach.
2. This solution gives you freedom with as many conditions as you want

Comment: Just tested and this works perfect.  However in the test example I only showed one destination city.  In the real world work book there are multiple orig and dest cities.

With your example I see it working for the orig city but could it be expanded to do a double match?

Comment: Without looking at the data it’s hard to definitely say yes, but I think so. Try yourself and let me know - if you find a problem I will try to help. You will probably need some other functions like AND, FILTER or QUERY to check multiple conditions.

Comment: I did some searching and found the INDEX option when working with multiple criteria.  Now this all seems simple int he examples on line right up until you I try to understand how to draw that data in from another workbook.

If you have a moment, my attempt at getting this to double match criteria is in a new tab on the lanes sheet titled INDEX TEST.  Not sure how close this is to being on track.

I put a more real world scenario in the rates sheet where the ORIG city is Mcclellan with multiple DEST cities that I would need to match both ORG and DEST to then drawn in that row of data.

Comment: @BobFranz - I have edited my answer. Now I hope it covers your needs fully.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That works flawlessly. Do not think I would have gotten there.

Answer (score 0):

More info would be helpful.

A couple ideas:

1. Using named ranges instead of a static reference. For example, if you create a named range in the rate sheet called MY_DATA that references A2!C600, you can include "MY_DATA" in your importrange in the vendor sheet.  Note that you'd still need to update MY_DATA every time you add a row.
2. If you're importing the entire sheet, perhaps omitting the end row would work (e.g. A2!C instead of A2!C600) - note that this means you need to use filter or query in the Vendor sheet to eliminate the blank rows.